# Using Hierarchical Bayesian Network for Data Smoothing

Tags: r, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, smoothing

I have a dataset that contains the mean speed at which 50 car models move, along with the standard deviation (based on an underlying database of sampled car speeds).

Using this mean and deviation, I can create a distribution of speeds for each car model. Some models' mean speed is informed by a lot of underlying sampled data, some by very few entries.

I am able to cluster the cars into different types (e.g. sports, trucks etc).

I would like to create a hierarchical bayesian network that groups either the underlying data for each cluster, or groups the distributions for each model within a cluster based on the number of samples, which then can use the posterior distribution of car speeds from the cluster as a prior for each car model within each cluster, to inform a distribution of speeds for each car model.

The benefit of doing so, would be to generate a distribution of speeds for car models that have a low amount of sampled data if I know which cluster it should belong to.

Is this possible? I'm used to using tools such as RStan/PyMC3 with independent variables used to predict a dependent variable and clustering there, but unsure how to formulate this problem similarly.